# POST to web service fails while GET succeeded: PHP

Tags: php

I have implemented a web service in PHP. This service takes name/value pairs as input and returns JSON encoded strings.

Everything was working as expected on my local apache web servers running on mac-osx and windows 7. However, after hosting my PHP scripts on this linux based web service provider, my POST requests to the service are failing.

By backend PHP script which fails is as follows:

```
if (session_id() == "") {
    session_start();
}

ob_start();

$command = isset($_REQUEST["Command"]) ? $_REQUEST["Command"] : "";
if ($command == "") {
    echo("Handler Not Found: ");
    print_r($_REQUEST);
}
```

The output from a POST request to the url with `Command=do_foo` is always `Handler Not Found:`. It is as if the web service never receives any of the parameters I send. The value of `$_REQUEST` is printed as:

```
[PHPSESSID] => db0af76fe8028e70dc96f816d0dbe927
```

If I change the invocation method to GET everything works as expected. What am I missing?

PS: I'm calling this web service in an Android app using `apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet` and `` `apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet ``. I have verified that the POST fails even if I send the POST request through the [FireFox add-on Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/)

EDIT:

1. I have the same problem if I use the `$_POST` super global.
2. I cannot ssh into my hosting server, but CPANEL is showing me that
       `register_globals=off`. I don't know if that can create problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the ini setting [variables-order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) or request-order. Maybe POST variables are disabled to be included in the `$_REQUEST` super-global.

Answer (score 2):

Probably `$_REQUEST` is disabled. You should use `$_POST` instead, it's more secure anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.htaccess` for a LIMIT entry, something like:

```
<Limit POST>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Limit>
```